# Easiest way to convert byte array into Blob in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob

What is the easiest way to convert byte array into Blob data type in MYSQL with java programming language?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Googling "java convert byte[] to sql.blob" gives a lot of hits ..

Comment: well i have been googling for some time now,thats y i finally thought of posting it here.I did convert byte array to a serialblob bt had a problem converting it back to a bytearray since my table column was of type blob.I am here to get a proper way of converting a byte array into a blob,thanks:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, bytes);
```

Comment: well, you need the connection object, obviously :)

Comment: `setBytes()` returns number of bytes written. Should we write it inside loop for partial write? or single line of code will suffice? I have a 50KB `byte[]` all in memory which I want to save.

Answer (score 3):

Blob fileBlob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byteArray);

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one, if you are using hibernate.. Possibly the easiest way! :)

```
Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(bytes);
```

Comment: this is deprecated. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#createBlob(java.io.InputStream)