# conversion of byte array into image(blob) in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans-7

The code for the image conversion from byte array to image i.e blob.

```
 try
 {
     Blob image_vis = rs1.getBlob(10);
     InputStream x=image_vis.getBinaryStream();
     OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(string_op);
     byte[] bytes = string_op.getBytes();
     String s=new String(bytes);
     System.out.println(+s);  //prints bytes for the string
     ImageIcon icon_cap = new ImageIcon(string_op);
     image_cap.setIcon(icon_cap);  //prints nothing to Jlabel
     //image_cap.setText(s);    //prints a path of a image
  }
```

I am able to get path of an image, but I am anable to convert it into image format, so that it will display on a form. please help me.

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849893/javahow-to-convert-byte-array-to-blob

Comment: I am unable to find the solution, thatswhy.... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This..

```
try
 {
Blob image_vis = rs1.getBlob("blobColumn");
int blobLength = (int) image_vis.length();  

byte[] bytes = image_vis.getBytes(1, blobLength);
image_vis.free();
final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("ImagePath/ImageName.jpg"));
}
```

Later you can pick up the image..