# How to assign blob image to JLabel

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans-7

I am storing the image and other details of visitor into table tbl_visitor. The code is as follows,

```
    String string_op="F:\\POSTERS\\Roses\\TROPIC4.png"; 
    File imageFile = new File(string_op);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

    String queryVis="insert into tbl_visitor(visitor_name,contact_no," +
            "job_profile,org_name,photo_id_proof,type_of_visitor,date," +
            "extra_people,image) values('"+
            name_of_visitor.getText()+"','"+
            contact_num.getText()+"','"+
            job_profile.getText()+"','"+
            org.getText()+"','"+
            photo_id_num.getText()+"','"+
            type_of_visitor.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+
            date_and_time.getText()+"','"+
            tf1.getText()+"','"+
            "fis,(int)imageFile.length()"+"')";
```

now I want to display the image on JFrame and to display the image am using the JLabel
but I am unable to assign image to the JLabel. I have tried following code for display the image, but its giving me error.

```
Blob image_vis = rs1.getBlob(10);
image_cap.setIcon(image_vis);
```

Please help me.

Comment: well, the parameter type of the SetIcon method must be of type ImageIcon.  So I would try casting the Blob to a ImageIcon.  Not 100% sure this will work though because I am not to familiar with the Blob class.

Comment: A single code line >400 chars wide?!?  You must have a **very wide** monitor.  For the sake of the rest of us, please force line breaks before SO introduces a scroll-bar.

Comment: See also this possible duplicate: [conversion of byte array into image(blob) in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860210/conversion-of-byte-array-into-imageblob-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you take some time to read the API doc:

Blob has a [getBinaryStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream%28%29) which returns a stream of bytes containing the data stored in the blob.

ImageIcon, which implements Icon, has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28byte%5B%5D%29) which takes a byte array as argument.

JLabel has a [setIcon(Icon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) method.

So, read everything from the Blob binary stream into a byte array, construct an ImageIcon using this byte array, and call the label setIcon method with this ImageIcon as argument.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please elaborate this statements by coding?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I won't do everything for you, no. Google for "Java IO tutorial" to understand how to read from an input stream to a byte array, or use Guava to do it for you. The rest is three lines of code.

Comment: T tried this code but it does not display imageBlob image_vis = rs1.getBlob(10);
       ObjectInputStream ois = null;
       ois = new ObjectInputStream(image_vis.getBinaryStream());
       ImageIcon image = (ImageIcon) ois.readObject();

Comment: My answer didn't tell you to do that at all. It said: read everything from the Blob binary stream **into a byte array**. Construct an ImageIcon **using this byte array** (and I even linked to the constructor you must use). Your code assumes you have a serialized ImageIcon object stored in the blob, which is not the case. Is it really so hard? Here's the whole code you need (with Guava): `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ByteStreams.toByteArray(blob.getBinaryStream())));`