# converting Image in memory to a Blob

Tags: java, image, oracle, jax-ws

I have an Image (type: java.awt.Image) in memory, I want to convert it to a Blob (type: java.sql.Blob) using jdk 1.7.

Everything I've been able to find on this subject uses streams and files.  Surely I don't need to save this Image to a file before being able to convert it??

Not much to show here, but an example follows:

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.awt.Image;

```
public GenericResponseType savePhoto(Image image)
{
       Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

       << some DB code and assembly of PreparedStatement >>

       Blob blob = conn.createBlob();

           << here's where the magic needs to happen I need to get the image parameter to blob >>
           // I've tried the following but doesn't quite work as it wants a RenderedImage
       // OutputStream os = blob.setBinaryStream(1);
       // ImageIO.write(parameters.getPhoto().getImage(), "jpg", os);


       pstmt.setBlob(4, blob);
     }
```

Some more detail (though I doubt it matters much) is that the above is generated using web services/JAX-WS from WSDL with an operation declared using MTOM.  So it generates a signature with an Image being passed as a variable.

Comment: No, but you will need to get it into a BufferedImage first

Answer (score 3):

`java.awt.Image` is pretty simply.  It does not provide any means by which the image can be written/saved nor does it provide any means to get access to underlying pixel data of the image.

The first step, is converting the `java.awt.Image` to something that `ImageIO` can support.  This will allow you to write the image data out...

`ImageIO` requires a `RenderedImage` as it's primary image source.  `BufferedImage` is the only implementation of this interface within the default libraries...

Unfortunately, there's no simply method for converting from one to the other.  Fortunately, it's not to hard.

```
Image img = ...;

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

Basically, this just paints the original `java.awt.Image` onto the `BufferedImage`

Next, we need to save the image in some way so that it can produce a `InputStream`...

This is a little less then optimal, but gets the job done.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
try {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);
} finally {
    try {
        baos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Basically, we write the image out to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and the use the result to generate a `ByteArrayInputStream`

Now.  If memory is an issue or the image is rather large, you can first write the image to a `File` and then simply read the `File` back in via some kind of `InputStream` instead...

Finally, we set the `InputStream` to the required column...

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
//...    
stmt.setBlob(parameterIndex, bais);
```

And Blob's your uncle...

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had seen the above as a possible approach but seemed like way too much work for something that on the surface seems like it should be very simple.  I may have to just go with the file IO.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: (probably a much easier process, this was just what I found after a quick goolge and cannot guarantee it'll work - Mads answer looks much more credible).

1. Get a BufferedImage ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605248/java-converting-image-to-bufferedimage))

   ```
   BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(scaleX, scaleY, TYPE);
   buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0 , null);
   ```
2. Get a byte array ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java))

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpg", baos );
   byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
   ```
3. Save byte array as blob ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662813/easiest-way-to-convert-byte-array-into-blob-in-java)) (but will should probably use a Prepared Statement)

   ```
   Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
   blob.setBytes(1, imageInByte);
   ```