# How can I convert BufferedImage to byte[]?

Tags: java, mysql, byte, arrays, bufferedimage

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    Connection cn = null;
    Object source = evt.getSource();

    JFileChooser filechooser= new JFileChooser();
    filechooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Your File");
    filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    int returnval=filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(returnval==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedImage bi;
        try
        {
            bi=ImageIO.read(file);
            lbl_movieCover.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
        //this.pack();
    }
```

Above is my code for choosing the image and displaying the image to `JLabel`.  My problem is that, I don't know how to convert it to `byte[]` so I could save it to my database.  By the way, I'm using MySQL for my database. If you guys know how to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Write it through `ImageIO.write` using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961065/converting-image-in-memory-to-a-blob/20961506#20961506)

Comment: Side note: with `catch(IOException e) {}` how will you know if something goes wrong?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you don't want to just copy the bytes from the file to the database?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ImageIO.write` to write the image through a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, for example

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
try {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);
} finally {
    try {
        baos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

You can then use the resulting `byte[]` array or `ByteArrayInputStream` and pass this to the `setBlob` method of a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ImageIO` to write an image to a byte array, like this:

```
static byte[] imageToByteArray(BufferedImage image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", stream);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        // This *shouldn't* happen with a ByteArrayOutputStream, but if it
        // somehow does happen, then we don't want to just ignore it
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return stream.toByteArray();
    // ByteArrayOutputStreams don't need to be closed (the documentation says so)
}
```

Comment: It should be stream.toByteArray();

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method-

```
/**
 * @param userSpaceImage
 * @return byte array of supplied image
 */
public byte[] getByteData(BufferedImage userSpaceImage) {
    WritableRaster raster = userSpaceImage.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    return buffer.getData();
}
```

Use it like-

```
//file from filechooser
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);
byte image[] = getByteData(originalImage);
```

Note that if image type is that of int e.g. BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB then
you will get cast exception. Following method can be used to convert to suitable type-

```
/**
 * this method convert supplied image to suitable type
 * it is needed because we need bytes of array so TYPE_INT images must be
 * converted to BYTE_BGR or so
 * @param originalImage loaded from file-chooser
 * @return 
 */

public BufferedImage convertImage(BufferedImage originalImage) {
    int newImageType = originalImage.getType();

    /**
     * Converting int to byte since byte array is needed later to modify 
     * the image
     */
    if (newImageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
            || newImageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR) {
        newImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    } else if (newImageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB) {
        newImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR;
    } else if (newImageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE) {
        newImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE;
    }
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), 
            originalImage.getHeight(), newImageType);
    Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While both @MadProgrammer's and @immibis' answers are technically correct and answers your question, you don't really want to copy an image file by decoding it, and re-encoding it. This is because it's *slower*, but more importantly, you will *lose quality* for certain image formats (most notably JPEG) and any *metadata associated with the image will be lost* (this last part could of course be intentional, but there are better ways to do this without ruining the image quality).

So, instead, do as @immibis seems to hint at in his comment, just open a `FileInputStream` and read the bytes directly from the file, and into the database. You should be able to open an `OutputStream` to the blob in your database as well, so you can save some memory (a good thing, if your files are large) by not reading the entire file contents into a byte array, before writing.

Something like:

```
File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();

// ... show image in label as before (but please, handle the IOException)

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
   Blob blob = ...; // Get from JDBC connection
   OutputStream output = blob.setBinaryStream(0);

   try {
      FileUtils.copy(input, output);
   }
   finally {
       output.close();
   }
}
finally {
    input.close();
}
```

`FileUtils.copy` can be implemented as:

```
public void copy(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int count;

    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    // Flush out stream, to write any remaining buffered data
    out.flush();
}
```