# How to add a photo to mysql from java?

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I've created a software using netbeans. now I want to add pictures to my database. I have created a table and changed the type as 'BLOB'. But, IDK how to code in java to do this.
with this, I get a image and set it to a jLabel.
now how to save this photo in mysql?

```
try {
            lbl_imge1.setIcon(null);
            jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
            BufferedImage upload = ImageIO.read(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile());
            java.awt.Image photo = upload.getScaledInstance(lbl_imge1.getWidth(), lbl_imge1.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            lbl_imge1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(photo));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I am here,

```
try {
            jLabel1.setIcon(null);
            jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
            BufferedImage upload = ImageIO.read(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile());
            java.awt.Image photo = upload.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(photo));

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crazy", "root", "123");

            BufferedImage buffered = ImageIO.read(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile());

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpg", baos);
            byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

            Blob blob = con.createBlob();
            blob.setBytes(1, imageInByte);

            String query="INSERT INTO image VALUES ('"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+blob+"')";
            PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(query);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Take your BufferedImage

   ```
   BufferedImage buffered= ImageIO.read(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile());
   ```
2. Get a byte array from it ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java))

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpg", baos );
   byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
   ```
3. Save byte array as blob ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662813/easiest-way-to-convert-byte-array-into-blob-in-java)) (probably use a Prepared Statement)

   ```
   Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
   blob.setBytes(1, imageInByte);
   ```

***UPDATE***: connection is your database connector i.e:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
```

Comment: Can you please describe the 3rd step? what is 'connection' ? netbeans gives me errors.

Comment: Is your connection to database! I.E: `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");` I updated the answer ;)

Comment: It depends of how you manage the relation btw your entitys and database... do you have `Hibernate Mappings` with `EntityManager`? maybe a simple `HQL` query is enough for you, do it as you do in other cases...  If no, `PreparedStatement` as suggested in answer... `String query = "insert into table(......)";
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);`

Comment: Statement statement=con.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO image VALUES ('"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+blob+"')"); this saves a memory address. Is that ok? if yes, how to get it back as an image?

Comment: now i tried the same query with PreparedStatement. but nothing happens. nothing saves in database.

Comment: Are you sure your `blob` is created correctly? If possible, please update your question to check in which point are you now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save any byte array to a blob column. I know that this is possible with Oracle and this also should work with MySql. 
Here is a small example how to do a insert with java code:

```
String sql = "insert into yourtable(id,binaryImage) values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt =dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(your_byte_array);
pstmt.setString(1, "your_id");
pstmt.setBinaryStream(2, bais);
pstmt.execute();
pstmt.close();
```